# How to call instance.delete() from a template?

Tags: django-templates, django-views

I have a 'for loop' in my Django template which displays all the entries for sale, I would like for the seller (assuming they are logged in), to be able to delete each entry if they choose.  I am not understanding how to accomplish this part.  I know how to delete an object in Python.

```
Entry.objects.filter(name="toaster").delete()
```

but I'm not understanding how to link or call this from the template.

What I would like to do, if at all possible is something like this in my template.

```
  {% for entry in latest_entries %}
       entry.name <a href="{{ entry.delete() }}">delete</a>
       entry.price
       entry.picture
       entry.sellername   
  {% endfor %}
```

Obviously this is broken and won't work, but I'd like to apply the same sort of logic if at all posible.

Can I accomplish this without adding any additional URL patterns?
Is there any way I can give the end user the ability to delete items without using Ajax, and without adding a URL pattern (for example I do not want to delete/entryname, I want the end user to be able to delete the item directly from the latest_entries page)?

I feel like either there is something very basic I'm not understanding here or this is more complicated than I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you must call the function to get entry deleted. You can call it using ajax or to send user to specific url accessible to privileged user and then return him back. In this situation I will create form with check box near to the entry. Then user can select entries and submit form. There is no other way.